# Colouring Book: Converting AS2 to AS3

Tags: flash, action, actionscript-2

Hi I'm currently making a colouring book and need to convert a bit of code from AS2 to AS3 as I am learning AS3 and have never looked as AS2. The code is:

```
stop();
_root.fillColor = 0xFFFFFF;
```

along with

```
on (press) {
color = new Color(this);
color.setRGB(_root.fillColor);
delete color;
}
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is code inside button, where as2 class `Color` apply to current object from `root.fillColor`

**UPDATE:**

In case, that event.target is awaiting button

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
...
function onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    const ct: ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    ct.color = COLOR_IN_HEX_FORMAT; // 0x00CC77
    (event.target as DisplayObject).transform.colorTransform = ct;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I fix this so the colouring book works? @dimpiax

Comment: by `colorTransform` property of `transform` object's property.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: you need translation from as2 to as3?